# Where is an initialized local variable's value stored before the stack in C?

Tags: c, variables, stack, local

I have a question about local variables. I am well aware that during a function call, the memory for the variable is allocated and after returning from the function, the memory is freed up. But from where does the program know what value to use during initialization?

```
void foo()
{
  uint8_t x = 2u;
}
```

So my question is, where is the value 2 stored in the memory before calling the function? My guess that it is in the text segment (in the non volatile memory) and is read from there to stack.

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: The involved meachanisms are not specified by C standard, at least not anywhere as detailed as necessary to answer this. It is implementation defined. Would you like to define the details of your environment?

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you very much for answering. My usecase is the following: I am using STM32F103 microcontroller and GNU Arm embedded toolchain. I have a software modul where I would like to validate a password. The validation is easy, there is a module which a bool validatePassword(uint16_t pw) function and in the function, the raw password value is xor'ed with a bitmask and compared with the encrypted result.The encrypted value is stored as a static const variable in the module and the bitmask is stored as a local uint16_t type variable in the function of the module.

Comment: So, simply, you compile your code with `gcc -S` and look into the generated assembly file `sourcefile.s` :D

Comment: The concept is to have the bitmask stored far away from the result in the memory. In runtime, the local variable is stored in the stack and the static const should be stored in the text area. But if the initialized value is also stored in the text area, it might be not as safe as I thought.

Comment: Your comments should be added to the question. The answer is that your scheme is fundamentally unsafe, and is easily reverse engineered regardless of how the compiler implements it. The correct way to implement a password is with non-reversible math. But a simple XOR is easily reversed.

Comment: Indeed it is not the perfect design, but currently I am more interested in the memory layout (and where the initial value is stored before function call) behind the program than in the math of my algorith as it is just a hobby project and the general question of initialized local variable storage came up during the implementation.

Comment: If you use a proper one-way hash function such as SHA-256, it doesn't matter what the memory layout is since the code won't contain anything an attacker can use.

Comment: @Yunnosch it is not implementation-defined. That term means that the Standard specifies that the implementation must document it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler gets to decide.

The value may not even be "stored" anywhere: for some constants (e.g. zero) it's easier to just emit code to compute the value on demand rather than copy it from anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for answering, @Daniel Pryden. In my application, it is not zero-initialized. What are the usual choices of the compiler? Usually the text area?

Comment: @LGy01 you could inspect the assembly that your compiler generates

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the compiler, of course, but whatever it is, it's going to be more or less the same as if you'd assigned a value to the variable within the expression.  That is, if you say

```
void foo()
{
    uint8_t x = 2u;
}
```

it's just as if you'd said

```
void foo()
{
    uint8_t x;    /* uninitialized */
    x = 2u;
}
```